# Display location Using Longitude/Latitude Coordinates - Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, coordinates

How can I input a set of coordinates and have Google maps show a location. This is all to be done through javascript (ie: no user interface)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I've asked the same and they answered --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766116/how-can-i-get-x-y-number-at-every-click-on-google-maps

Comment: @SamekaTV - That link is the OPPOSITE goal (clicking on a map, and getting back longitude/latitude). THIS question is GIVEN a known longitude/latitude, how display the map of that location. (OR maybe shahmeer was asking the related question, of how to show a marker at that location, on a map that is already open.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Note: If you already have a latitude/longitude, see [Alteveer’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7135770/199364).*

You'll need to need to use a geolocation service to get the latitude/longitude. Google Maps has one built in:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Geocoding

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
<!-- Placeholder for the Google Map -->
<div id="map" style="height: 512px;">
  <noscript>
    <!-- http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/ -->
    <img src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=1%20infinite%20loop%20cupertino%20ca%2095014&amp;zoom=16&amp;size=512x512&amp;maptype=roadmap&amp;sensor=false" />
  </noscript>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Define the address we want to map.
var address = "1 infinite loop cupertino ca 95014";

// Create a new Geocoder
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

// Locate the address using the Geocoder.
geocoder.geocode( { "address": address }, function(results, status) {

  // If the Geocoding was successful
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

    // Create a Google Map at the latitude/longitude returned by the Geocoder.
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 16,
      center: results[0].geometry.location,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

    // Add a marker at the address.
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: results[0].geometry.location
    });

  } else {
    try {
      console.error("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    } catch(e) {}
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: This answers a different question than was asked. The question asked is:  given LATITUDE/LONGITUDE, display a map, or a marker on a map. This answer is: given an ADDRESS, display a marker on a map.
 **If already have lat/long**, then see the lines under `// Add a marker at the address.` to display a marker.  Or if want to open a new map, see [Alteveer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7135770/199364).

Comment: That’s a great point, Steve. (Oops!) I added a note to this answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to initialize the map with latitude/longitude as follows: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#MapOptions