# How can I get x and y number at every click event on Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

I want to retrieve x/y coordinates at every click-event on Google Maps.

Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (e) {
        document.form1.waypointLog.value = e.latLng.lat().toFixed(6)
        + ' |' + e.latLng.lng().toFixed(6);

});
```

**Source:** https://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/3f4329e3a20e7b0b

You can also check: http://forums.gpsreview.net/viewtopic.php?t=3632