# Google Maps API not returning latitude or longitude and autocomplete not working

Tags: javascript, html, api, model-view-controller

I want to get get the coordinates of a location using JavaScript. However I'm having trouble with my autocomplete. I came across a similar query but non of the solutions have helped me out.

My code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Geocoding</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initilize);
    function initilize() {
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('txtautocomplete'));
        google.maps.events.AddListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
            var places = autocomplete.getPlace();
            var location = "<b>Location:</b>" + places.formatted_address + "<br/>";
            location += "<b>Latitude:</b>" + places.geometry.location.lat + "<br/>";
            location += "<b>Longitude:</b>" + places.geometry.location.lng + "<br/>";
            document.getElementById('lblresult').innerHTML = location;
        });

    };
</script>
location:<input type="text" id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter the address"/> <br/> <br/>
<label id="lblresult"></label>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7135722/display-location-using-longitude-latitude-coordinates-google-maps

Answer (score 0):

Try to have a look at the first answer to this question:
[Google map api get Latitude and longitude from autocomplete without map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478646/google-map-api-get-latitude-and-longitude-from-autocomplete-without-map)

it seems like its the answer for your issue too